# Control power settings via command-line only

Tags: debian, command-line, power-management

I have old Samsung N220 netbook running Debian 11.3 that I have configured as an octoprint server.

I have managed to get the system to stop entering suspend when the lid is closed, but would like to have some additional control. My aim is to have the system run as normal under AC power, but suspend when the AC power is shut off.

After spending hours googling this I can only find options for setting these variables from a GUI environment which - seeing as its intentionally running with zero gui - is not possible.

If anyone can provide a solution for this I would be very appreciative.